# Custom Tag Page in Docusaurus

Tags: markdown, docusaurus

I want to create a custom Tag Page for docusaurus. I am using the classic theme and successfully swizzled `DocTagDocListPage`. So now I can change the *template* for all tag pages.

What I want to do is have a custom markdown page for the route `docs/tags/contribute` e.g. It would be great to just create that file in `docs/tags/contribute.md` to have that page but docusaurus is complaining with the following warning.

```
[WARNING] Duplicate routes found!
- Attempting to create page at /docs/tags/contribute, but a page already exists at this route.
This could lead to non-deterministic routing behavior.
```

Is there an easy way to setup that page without having to write my own theme? Or for my markdown page to take precedence over the theme route?

Comment: if the answer I provided resolves your problem, consider approving it to make it easier for other developers to find the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have already created a page for `/docs/tags` by swizzling `DocTagDocListPage`, you can use the `plugin-content-pages` plugin to create a custom page for `/docs/tags/contribute`.

First, install the `plugin-content-pages` package:

```
npm install @docusaurus/plugin-content-pages
```

Then, you need to configure yout `docusaurus.config.js` file:

```
module.exports = {
  // ...
  plugins: [
    [
      "@docusaurus/plugin-content-pages",
      {
        id: "tags-contribute",
        path: "tags/contribute",
        routeBasePath: "docs",
      },
    ],
  ],
};
```

This configuration tells `Docusaurus` to generate a page with the ID `tags-contribute` for the markdown file located at `docs/tags/contribute.md`, and to use the `/docs` route base path.

Now you can create the `docs/tags/contribute.md` file. and `Docusaurus` will generate a page for `/docs/tags/contribute` with the content from `docs/tags/contribute.md`.

Keep in mind that if you have conflicting routes, `Docusaurus` will put priority on the one which appears first in your configuration. In this case, since the `DocTagDocListPage` was already swizzled, you can be assured that your custom page will take precedence.

Comment: The last part is unfortunately not correct. Docusaurus states that it will not guarantee which route it gives priority `This could lead to non-deterministic routing behavior.` My goal is to use default tag pages where available, but to use my custom tag pages if i specified some.